# Android app that communicates with a server-side script

Tags: android

I am new to android but have a term worth of experience with Java which isn’t much at all but have a decent understanding of the important pillars of OOP.

I have been assigned a task to create an android app the communicates with a server-side script. To give some background my teacher has collected around 400,000 data entries and placed them in a MySQL database and has written the PHP script that will query the database which returns the results in JSON format. 
What I am required to do is create an android app that will query this server-side script to display the information in my app.

Where do I start to accomplish this? I currently have a very basic understanding of android having just gone through stuff like, Application Manifest file, resources, activities, views, services, layouts, resources, widgets etc. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**To fetch data:**

- `Retrofit` library (to fetch data)
  https://square.github.io/retrofit/
- `GSON` libarary (to parse data from `.json` to Java/Kotlin structure)
  https://github.com/google/gson
- `LiveData` from Android Architecture Components (to "wait" for data or "Observe" them)
  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

**To display data:**

- `RecyclerView` with `ViewHandler` pattern
  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

**To store data locally:**

- `Room` library (as abstraction layer over SQLite)
  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

**Some extra features**

- Swipe-to-Refresh (to send new request after swipe from top) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html
- `Shimmer` (to make loading more beautiful) https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android
- `ConstraintLayout` (as most modern layout for Android)
  https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout